# Bitpay xPrivKey to private key

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, private-key, bitpay, private-key-import

Network: BCH testnet
Client: bitcoin-abc-0.18/bin/bitcoind and bitcoin-cli

I want to convert xPrivKey which is from exported Bitpay wallet file to private key for using `bitcoin-cli importprivkey`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`xPrivKey` is a [BIP32 extended key](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki#extended-keys). This can be used to derive child addresses.

`importprivkey` expects a `WIF` [Wallet Import Format](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format).

In order to convert to from the extended to compressed format, all you need to do is decode from [Base58Check](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Base58Check_encoding) and grab the last 32 bytes (33 for public keys). See [BIP32 - Extended Key Serialization](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki#serialization-format) and then encode to WIF format:

`$ printf "xprv9uHRZZhk6KAJC1avXpDAp4MDc3sQKNxDiPvvkX8Br5ngLNv1TxvUxt4cV1rGL5hj6KCesnDYUhd7oWgT11eZG7XnxHrnYeSvkzY7d2bhkJ7" | base58 -dc | xxd -p 0488ade4013442193e8000000047fdacbd0f1097043b78c63c20c34ef4ed9a111d980047ad16282c7ae623614100edb2e14f9ee77d26dd93b4ecede8d16ed408ce149b6cd80b0715a2d911a0afea`

The last 64 characters (32 bytes) represent the hex version of the private key.

`edb2e14f9ee77d26dd93b4ecede8d16ed408ce149b6cd80b0715a2d911a0afea`

Then convert to WIF:

```
$ priv="edb2e14f9ee77d26dd93b4ecede8d16ed408ce149b6cd80b0715a2d911a0afea"
$ # 0x80 for mainnet, 0xef for testnet
$ pub_suffix=01 # append 01 if the corresponding public key is compressed
$ mainnet_prefix=80
$ ext_priv_mainnet=$mainnet_prefix$priv
$ wif_enc_mainnet_compressed=$(printf "$ext_priv_mainnet$pub_suffix" | xxd -r -p | base58 -c)
$ echo "WIF Mainnet (Compressed): "$wif_enc_mainnet_compressed

WIF Mainnet (Compressed): L5BmPijJjrKbiUfG4zbiFKNqkvuJ8usooJmzuD7Z8dkRoTThYnAT
```

Comment: where are you getting this base58 program?

Comment: Good question, I think it was `pip install base58`